# Struts , JSON, Ignore some properties

Tags: java, jquery, json, struts

i have a form (displayed on the client) with several fields , and some fields are filled with JSON (like country List). the problem is evry time JSON filled the locations lists it throws an ognl.OgnlException cause it cannot see the auther properties (from the form) on the JSON CLASS!!!

so i'm looking for a way to make my JSON class to ignore those properties, whose has to be treated on another Action CLASS!!!

Comment: Are you using struts-json plugin? If yes, it has include/exclude properties which can be configured in `struts.xml`. If you are using external lib to convert an object to JSON, then the plugin would have an addition argument to pass the include and exclude list.

Comment: http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/apache/struts/struts2-json-plugin/2.1.8/struts2-json-plugin-2.1.8-javadoc.jar!/index.html

Comment: i have tried those parametes, and it seems that my JSON still trying to read the properties that missing !!!

Comment: and yes , i'm using struts json plugin !!!!